# Using RegExp to extract the first 2 words (3 including a dash) from a SELECT in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column which contains multiple values in a single column in the format :

```
[word] - [word] - [word] - [word]
```

so it would look like :

```
GEO - MRVES - EKBASDSS - MO
```

How can I write a query that will extract the first part.
 So from the example above I want "`GEO - MRVES`". There is no set length for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^-]+-[^-]+', 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this worked. What are the ,1,1 for? Just wanted to understand why this works.

Comment: @RobBlagg . . . https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.column_one, 1, INSTR(t.column_one, '-', 1, 2) -1) AS col_one
FROM your_table t;
```

Look for the second occurence of `-` using INSTR and cut from the start of the string to that position - 1